# TinyMce image_advtab Style input missing

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-6

Adding the Advanced tab to the TinyMce image editor does not add a Style input.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea#basic-example',
  height: 500,
  plugins: 'image',
  toolbar: 'image',
  image_advtab: true
});
```

Screenshot of Image Editor: [Advanced tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caOcw.png)

I tried the above code by starting with the Basic Example from here:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/basic-example/